# stopping Spinner ItemSelected from firing on SetSelection

Tags: android

I want to turn off getting onItemSelectedListener when I do

```
spinInsuranceList.setSelection(previousSpinnerPos);
```

I already made custom class, but now I want to override **onItemSelected** and make same method with my own extra parameter which help me to stop fire event.

Please Note: I already implemented spinner and it is working fine, so because of **onItemSelected** custom impl, my exisiting work should not effect.

Code:
CustomSpinnerClass: (I made this custom class, because that time I wanted to click on same item which is selected previously)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class CustomSpinnerClass extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner {

    public CustomSpinnerClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSpinnerClass(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
    }

    public CustomSpinnerClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
            //TODO:-> Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
            //TODO:-> Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
        }
    }
}
```

I found this solution, but don't know how to use:

```
private Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener spinnerListener
= new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener(){
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
int arg2, long arg3) {
/* This function is called when you select something from the spinner */
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
/**This line sets the index of the spinner.
Here I have given it as position which
can be  any number with in the index range  ***/
my_spinner.setSelection(position);
}};
```

Please read, if you don't understood my requirement: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6350/help-stopping-spinner-itemselected-from-firing-on-setselection

Comment: can you explain your requirement , what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni I heartly request you to please read this dear: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6350/help-stopping-spinner-itemselected-from-firing-on-setselection

Comment: you can do one thing, manage one boolen variable by default false. Now in listener check if this variable is false dont run your code. in else condition true this variable. so the listener will call but your code will not execute first time when you are setting value.
Try this i also did same in my codes and it s working fine

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni I tried all those, it affects to other things and also my code based on add/edit text and written differently according to client requirement.

Comment: thats why i ask you for exact requirement. If you are getting data from local database you only need to set data for first time, then it must work as usual so what is issue

Answer (score 1):

When I want to set something without firing the listener what I do is

```
spinner.setSelectionListener(null);
spinner.setSelection(20);
spinner.setSelectionListener(this);
```

Comment: what is spinner, it is a Spinner spinner?   spinInsuranceList.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
                    spinInsuranceList.setSelection(previousSpinnerPos);
                    spinInsuranceList.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: I'm getting this not spinner.setSelectionListener(null);

Comment: That is not an actual example, Just to give you an idea. Basically, set the listener to null before you call  `setSelection()` and then set the listener back again. This way your listener is null when you are calling `setSelection()` and wont be fired. Let me know if this solved your problem.

Comment: i don't think so it is good idea "spinner.setSelectionListener(null);" every time need to re-initialize the code

Comment: I'm trying, but can you do some research too and give me solution? Please..

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni that's why, but I'm not finding any other solution

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni it is wrking, if I do null, but when to it back? if I do in same line, it'll repeat same thing and getting fired!

Comment: Yes obviously @kimy. In spinner, checkbox everywhere when you tried to set data in that it will always call his listener. So you can use a flag to avoid this.

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni Because of some sitiuation, I'm unable to do this using flag. I tried but the prob is when I do null, set pos and again if user wanted to click that time it should be not null! Can you tell me that how to know when user click on spinner? I tried on layout but it's not worh it, crashing

Comment: can i know that situation why u can't use flag, because if you make this so critical the it will work now but when data increase your code will not work so please tell me that situation.